# Setting scrollTop makes the scrolling very slow

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have 2 divs one after other. When i scroll the div 1 then div2 should also scroll and the same if i scroll div2 then div1 should scroll. I implemented this by setting the scrollTop value of div 1 to div2 and div2 to div1. But the problem here is the scroll event is getting triggered multiple time and the scrolling is very very slow. I have created a live demo can any one help me out?

```js
(function() {
  var target = $("#tableFixed");
  $("#tableLista").scroll(function(e) {
    target.prop("scrollTop", this.scrollTop)
      .prop("scrollLeft", this.scrollLeft);
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  var target1 = $("#tableLista");
  $("#tableFixed").scroll(function(e) {
    target1.prop("scrollTop", this.scrollTop)
      .prop("scrollLeft", this.scrollLeft);
    e.preventDefault();
  });

})();
```

```css
.divScrollDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.tableNoScroll {
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

  <body>
    <p>Scroll the left div, watch the right one.</p>

    <table id="tableFixed" class="divScrollDiv tableNoScroll">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>17</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>19</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <table id="tableLista" class="divScrollDiv">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
          <td>g</td>
          <td>h</td>
          <td>i</td>
          <td>j</td>
          <td>k</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Code pen link: https://codepen.io/velramesh08121988/pen/ExPNgdV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some kind of locking to prevent triggering `scroll` in loops. A simple primitive lock could track which table you are hovering and only trigger synchronization for that element.

```
  var scrollSource;
  var setScrollSource = function() {
    scrollSource = this;
  }
  target.hover(setScrollSource);
  target1.hover(setScrollSource);

  target.scroll(function (e) {
    if (this !== scrollSource) {
      return;
    }
    // sync logic
  }

  target1.scroll(function (e) {
    if (this !== scrollSource) {
      return;
    }
    // sync logic
  }
```

```js
(function () {
  var target = $("#tableFixed");
  var target1 = $("#tableLista");

  var scrollSource;
  var setScrollSource = function() {
    scrollSource = this;
  }
  target.hover(setScrollSource);
  target1.hover(setScrollSource);

  target1.scroll(function (e) {
    if (this !== scrollSource) {
      return;
    }
    target
      .prop("scrollTop", this.scrollTop)
      .prop("scrollLeft", this.scrollLeft);
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  target.scroll(function (e) {
    if (this !== scrollSource) {
      return;
    }
    target1
      .prop("scrollTop", this.scrollTop)
      .prop("scrollLeft", this.scrollLeft);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
})();
```

```css
.divScrollDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.tableNoScroll {
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p>Scroll the left div, watch the right one.</p>

  <table id="tableFixed" class="divScrollDiv tableNoScroll">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>15</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>16</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>17</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>18</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>19</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table id="tableLista" class="divScrollDiv">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
        <td>k</td>
        <td>l</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
        <td>k</td>
        <td>l</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
        <td>k</td>
        <td>l</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
        <td>k</td>
        <td>l</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
        <td>k</td>
        <td>l</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
        <td>k</td>
        <td>l</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
        <td>k</td>
        <td>l</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
        <td>k</td>
        <td>l</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
        <td>k</td>
        <td>l</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
        <td>k</td>
        <td>l</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
        <td>k</td>
        <td>l</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
        <td>k</td>
        <td>l</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
        <td>k</td>
        <td>l</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
        <td>k</td>
        <td>l</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
        <td>k</td>
        <td>l</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
        <td>k</td>
        <td>l</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>g</td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td>i</td>
        <td>j</td>
        <td>k</td>
        <td>l</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```